# Taylor Series Expansion for ${z^2+4z^4+z^6}/(1-z^2)^3$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

So I know for sure that the Taylor Series expansion for $1/(1-z^2)^3$ is $\sum {k(k-1)z^{2k-4}/{2}} $ assuming |x|<1. But what do we do with the top?  I think its already in the expanded form, right?  If not, then what manipulation would we need to take to get into final form?

Comment: The title shows ${z^2+4z^4+z^6}/(1-z^2)^3$ but I have the feeling that it should be $\frac{z^2+4z^4+z^6} {(1-z^2)^3}$. Could you fix it if needed ? At least, if this is the case, write it as $(z^2+4z^4+z^6)/(1-z^2)^3$

Answer (score 0):

Yes multiply your numerator with $\sum k(k-1)z^{2k-4}/2$ and match like terms. You'll have

$$\sum k(k-1)z^{2k-2}/2+\sum 2k(k-1)z^{2k}+\sum k(k-1)z^{2k+2}/2$$

Now you can shift the summation variables in each term to get those exponents of $z$ to match, giving you your answer. I'll leave that to you.